# Simplifying $f(x) = \left(x^{3} + 2x^{2} + O(x)\right)\cdot\left(1 + \frac{1}{x} + O\left(\frac{1}{x^{2}}\right)\right) $

Tags: calculus, asymptotics

> Simplify $$f(x) = \Big(x^{3} + 2x^{2} + O(x)\Big)⋅\Bigg(1 + \frac{1}{x} + O\bigg(\frac{1}{x^{2}}\bigg)\Bigg) $$ 
>   as $x \to +\infty$.

I am a bit stuck as to what to do with the three sets of Big-Os I have at the end. Am I meant to just keep the lowest one?

I end up with these values

$$x^3+3x^2+2x+O(x)+O(1)+O\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)$$

Your help is appreciated.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews I have edited as advised. Thanks!

Comment: @matthias: use x^p in TeX to format exponents.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remember that $O(x^p)\subset O(x^q)$ whenever $p\leq q$ (assuming Big-O is understood as $x\rightarrow\infty$).

In other words, statements like $f(x)=O(x)+O(x^2)$ are redundant; we can just write $f(x)=O(x^2)$.

Comment: so in this case where (i think) I get  $ O(x)+O(1)+O(\frac{1}{x}) $  do I leave the largest or the smallest?

Comment: Hint: remember the def'n of Big-O. Perhaps ask yourself which of the three functions grows the fastest, $x$, $1$, or $1/x$?

Comment: I see. Makes sense, thanks for your help!